# How to await Firebase admin.auth().getUser() function

Tags: javascript, firebase, server, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that is supposed to return a user's email from using the Firebase admin API getUser(uid) function,

```
function getEmail(uid){
  var email;
  admin.auth().getUser(uid)
    .then((userRecord) => {
       return userRecord.email;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });
}
```

But in my other function when I make a variable that calls the function,

email = getEmail(uid);

the value in email is undefined, because the getUser function has returned a promise. How do I make the function getEmail wait to get the value of userRecord before returning?

I've tried adding await statements in different parts of the function but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. I'm a beginner in using the Google API.

Comment: `email = await getEmail(uid);` would be my guess. But then you have to return a Promise from `getEmail`.

Answer (score 1):

Return the Promise that you get from `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` in your `getEmail` function.

```
function getEmail(uid) {
  return admin.auth().getUser(uid)
    .then((userRecord) => {
       return userRecord.email;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });
}
```

Then either use the returned Promise to chain a `then` callback.

```
getEmail(uid).then(email => {
  console.log(email);
});
```

Or await it in an `async` function.

```
async function main() {
  const email = await getEmail(uid);
  console.log(email);
}

main();
```

---

### Edit

As you explained in your comment below:

> basically, I just want the code to run as if it were all synchronous/ line-by-line.

It's impossible to make asynchronous code synchronous, but it is possible to make it run line-by-line with [`async / await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax. Promises that are being *awaited* in an async function will run line by line as you're telling the code to wait for it to resolve before going to the next line.

I've modified the code from your CodePen to include the aforementioned syntax. We're still using the same `getEmail` function that returns the promise from `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` and just wait for it to finish before doing something with the result.

```
function getEmail(uid) {
  return admin.auth().getUser(uid)
    .then((userRecord) => {
       return userRecord.email;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });
}

app.post("/sendx", async (req, res) => {
  const uid = req.body.x.user.uid;
  const email = await getEmail(uid);
  let verified = false;

  /*console.log(email.substring(email.indexOf('@')));
  if (email.substring(email.indexOf('@')) == "@xxx.edu") {
    verified = true; 
  }*/

  res.send({ verified });
});
```

I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried adding the function with the await statement and returned the const email but it's still returning undefined. I also tried the .then block but I get the same ".then() is undefined" error.

Comment: To isolate the error I have this block of code: `var email;
   admin.auth().getUser(uid)
    .then((userRecord) => {
       email = userRecord.email;
      console.log(email);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
    });

  console.log("hi");` The "hi" appears in the console before the email. I don't really know what's going on

Comment: Could you post the implementation of this answer in a codepen, jsfiddle or otherwise to show us? And for the second comment. `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` returns a `Promise`. Promises are asynchronous. That means that while `admin.auth().getUser(uid)` is running it's going to let other code run first instead of blocking the thread. So `"hi"` will be logged first because the promise lets it. Only whenever the promise has been *resolved* (succesfully finished) then it will continue with whatever happens the `then` callback function.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Here is a codepen link, I deleted some lines that had the firebase api key/other information:   https://codepen.io/sage31/pen/NWzdVzE?editors=1010 -- basically, I just want the code to run as if it were all synchronous/ line-by-line

Comment: Thank you for the additional code. Having a context helps a lot. I've modified my answer to include the code from your pen.